# How to convert a string to a single-element list?

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog and I would like to convert a string: `'test string'` to an array with a single element: `['test string']` so I can append it to an existing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write it as is:

```
X='test string'.
List=[X].
```

Comment: Note that 'test string' is an _atom_ (an identifier) whereas "test string" is a _string_ (a text to be used in text processing). These two usages have been traditionally merged in Prolog, but not so in SWI-Prolog (although making the difference leads to a number of headscratchers).